# How can I correctly print the object content in PHP?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am absolutly new in **PHP** and moreover in **Laravel** framework and I have the following problem.

I am doing:

```
    $attributes = array(
        'id' => $dettagliLogin->id,
        'username' => $dettagliLogin->email,
        'name' => $dettagliLogin->userName,
    );

    $user = new GenericUser($attributes);

    \Log::info('USER: '.(var_dump(($user))));
```

Where the last line:

```
\Log::info('USER: '.(var_dump(($user))));
```

should write the content of the **$user** object into a log file.

The problem is that into my log file I obtain this output:

```
[2017-01-30 10:25:19] local.INFO: USER:
```

so it is as this object is empty but I think that it is not empty because then is used.

Why? How can I correctly print the object content?

Comment: if you just want to print, try `dd($user);`

Comment: var_dump() displays on screen; var_export() returns a variable with the display content that can be written to a log file

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want to use `var_export` - [here's the docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-export.php)

```
\Log::info('USER: ' . var_export($user, true));
```

With the 2nd param set as `true`, this exports the contents of the supplied variable as an assignable string, rather than printing them straight onto the page.

**Edit**: I've also tidied up your code a little as you'd gone a bit nuts with braces!

Answer (score 2):

`var_dump` [does not have any return value](http://php.net/manual/de/function.var-dump.php), it outputs directly to stdOut. That's why you don't see anything there.

Use [`var_export`](http://php.net/manual/de/function.var-export.php) with a second parameter of `true` to save the contents in a string.

Answer (score -2):

Maybe you have too many '('

Try :

```
\Log::info('USER: '.var_dump($user));
```

If it doesn't work force your var_dump to be a string but normally you don't need to do that.

Hope it will help you :)